# What sites discuss Geomedia products?

Tags: geomedia, intergraph

Do you know about any site where there is any discussion on Geomedia products (besides Intergraph Synergy site which is not very active lately)?

Comment: I think that should be discussed on http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com - but it is a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I would just ask any Geomedia related questions you have and let it expand that way. I'm sure once there are some questions on the subject there will be more traffic. Remember the site is still in beta and just starting out.

Also feel free to add Geomedia info to existing questions if you are able; eg where a question states "how do I do xxxx" then you might explain how it is done in Geomedia. Again it helps increase the Geomedia profile.

Answer (score 1):

http://jeffhobbs.net/ has good links and content.

used it Geomedia once found it buggy, but now there is better open source GIS software so makes sense to use that instead.

Comment: I cannot replace GM just like that because we have number of applications built on Geomedia platform.

Comment: what open source GIS software are you referring to?

Comment: QGIS (Quantum GIS) http://www.qgis.org/